# Sorting by last field and printing whole line

Tags: linux, sorting, awk

I am trying to sort a file of names by last name using awk and sort. Some don't have middle names. Here's an example:

```
Rachel K Green
Chandler M Bing
Ross E Geller
Phoebe Buffay
Monica E Geller
Joey F Tribbiani
```

What I've tried is:

```
awk -F " " '{print $NF, $0}' names.txt | sort
```

This prints:

```
Bing Chandler M Bing
Buffay Phoebe Buffay
Geller Monica E Geller
Geller Ross E Geller
Green Rachel K Green
Tribbiani Joey F Tribbiani
```

I do understand why it's printing the last name and then the full line. I can't figure out how to sort by the last name, and then print the line. If i just use $0, without $NF, it doesn't sort it by last name.

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk -F " " '{print $NF, $0}' names.txt | sort | sed -r 's/^[^ ]+ //'
```

In the end, remove before first blank.

for the new order, my first solution kept the sorted order, but removed the last name:

```
 awk -F " " '{print $NF, $0}' names.txt | sort | sed -r 's/ [^ ]+$//'
```

In the end, remove after last blank.

Comment: Ok, that's clever.

Comment: I think OP wants to preserve original format.. so, first field has to be deleted after sort, not last field

Comment: That is a good point, this provided the traditional, *Last First Mi*, but I could see the desire being *First Mi Last*, but sorted.

Comment: Sorry, implemented the correct order. :) Hope I got it right now, removed first, not last name.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print $NF, $0}' names.txt | sort -k1 | cut -d ' ' -f2-
Chandler M Bing
Phoebe Buffay
Monica E Geller
Ross E Geller
Rachel K Green
Joey F Tribbiani
```

`cut -d ' '-f2-` prints back the original line by removing the last field `$NF` that `awk` printed for `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

With `gawk` and [array sorting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning)

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"}
       {a[$NF,$0]=$0} END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' names.txt
Chandler M Bing
Phoebe Buffay
Monica E Geller
Ross E Geller
Rachel K Green
Joey F Tribbiani
```

- `a[$NF,$0]=$0` use lastname and entire line as key (lastname alone is not enough because there are duplicates)
- `END{for(i in a) print a[i]}` print the array contents at end

If `ruby` is okay and same format as input is required

```
$ ruby -e 'print *readlines.sort_by {|s| s.split[-1]}' names.txt
Chandler M Bing
Phoebe Buffay
Ross E Geller
Monica E Geller
Rachel K Green
Joey F Tribbiani
```

- `readlines` will get all input lines in an array
- `sort_by` to give a custom sort key
- `{|s| s.split[-1]}` block which defines the custom sort, `s.split` will split on whitespaces and `-1` will be index of last element
- in case of tie, original input order is maintained